# Zappa serverless aws lambda issue

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-architecture, zappa

With Zappa sample application to deploy into AWS using zappa deploy command, all the steps are happening as expected as shown below.

```
(env) E:\Projects_EDrive\AWS\Zappa\zappa_examples\Zappa\example>zappa deploy dev_api
(Werkzeug 0.12.2 (c:\python27\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('Werkzeug==0.12'), set([u'zappa']))
Calling deploy for stage dev_api..
Downloading and installing dependencies..
Packaging project as zip.
Uploading dev-api-zappa-test-flask-app-dev-api-1503456512.zip (302.6KiB)..
100%|#######################################################################################################################| 310K/310K [00:08<00:00, 37.9KB/s]
Uploading dev-api-zappa-test-flask-app-dev-api-template-1503456531.json (1.6KiB)..
100%|#####################################################################################################################| 1.65K/1.65K [00:01<00:00, 1.04KB/s]
Waiting for stack dev-api-zappa-test-flask-app-dev-api to create (this can take a bit)..
 75%|############################################################################################2                              | 3/4 [00:10<00:05,  5.56s/res]
Deploying API Gateway..
Deployment complete!: https://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev_api
```

But when accessing above endpoint , getting internal error response.
Later verified created S3 bucket, there is no file uploaded. Empty bucket.

Later verified lambda as well, it has got default code. Hence getting internal error response. As per logs, it has got no module named **builtins**.

**"Unable to import module 'handler': No module named builtins"**

How to debug zappa deployment and how to install python packages ?

Comment: The empty bucket is to be expected, as Zappa deletes the uploaded `.zip` from S3 once the deployment is complete.

Answer (score 1):

You could try troubleshooting with [Python-lambda-local](https://github.com/HDE/python-lambda-local) tool. It tries it's best to mimic the real Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dependencies and Recreate the Virtualenv. It should work.
Ref: https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/1222