# ImportError while using AWS Lambda in Python (via zappa serverless); Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, aws-lambda, zappa, python-zappa

I have an `ImportError` issue with my **AWS Lambda** function

1. I can run this code locally without `ImportError`
2. I use `zappa` serverless for uploading my code to AWS Lambda--which requires a virtual environment and is an end-to-end solution for creating and updating Lambda functions
3. I previously had this code working on AWS Lambda

I'm not sure of the change I made (#3) that made this code go from working to `ImportError`. The log output is as follows.

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'dailycore': Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "/var/lang/bin/python3.8"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.23.3"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

I'm unclear if this is a Numpy issue, a Python issue, or a Zappa issue. Two changes I made that may have had an impact:

1. I separated out some of my personal code, uploaded it to github, and installed it as packages within the virtual environment using `pip`
2. I uninstalled Python from my machine and reinstalled it--as I had two versions causing conflict. Upon my reinstallation (Python 3.8), I changed the installation directory from its default.

The code runs from VS Code locally and wholly contained from within the virtual environment (i.e. I don't have any packages installed via pip on my machine outside of virtual environments at this point). The suggestions above may or may apply to this error. I've tried adding a system PATH variable to my Python 3.8 directory. I've tried downgrading numpy to `1.23.0`. I've tried uninstalling all dependencies within the virtual environment and reinstalling them.

**UPDATE**: I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53012580/6592059) and am looking into these comments: https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/1222

**UPDATE2**: I deleted the virtual environment and re-created per a suggestion at the link above. This did not work.

**UPDATE3**: I think my issue relates to the private package dependencies I installed via pip from my personal github repos (#2-2). This [link may be related](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/eov3xx/lambda_python_unable_to_import_module_main_no/). Something about dependencies not being at the top level. I am unsure how to fix this issue and/or repackage my private repo or install correctly. Any clarification is appreciated.

**UPDATE4**: I've isolated my issue to the private package dependencies and how they get called. A the solution may be related to Lambda Layers, [tutorial here](https://medium.com/the-cloud-architect/getting-started-with-aws-lambda-layers-for-python-6e10b1f9a5d). Looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

The `ImportModuleError` is related to this python package: [alpha_vantage](https://github.com/RomelTorres/alpha_vantage) **and not** either of my initial theories. I am unsure as to why, though. It seems like it has something to do with Alpha Vantage's `setup.py` file; although I could be mistaken.

I have removed the reference to Alpha Vantage for now, but if anyone knows why installing this package would throw a `numpy` error, please elaborate. I think the only reference to `numpy` would be through the `pandas` package--which is only an optional install (i.e. `extras_requires` in `setup.py`)